# ¿Cómo hago para que VSC me muestre la consola de GitBash?

Tags: vscode, terminal, git-bash

Instale *VSC*, después *Gitbash* (donde seleccioné *VSC* como editor de texto predeterminado) y al correr *VSC* y querer abrir una nueva terminal con *GitBash*, no me aparece como opción para elegirla.

Especifiqué bien la dirección en el **JSON**, dentro de las configuraciones, `terminal, integrated: shell windows`. *GitBash* está en un disco distinto al que contiene el *Windows 10*, por eso especifiqué la dirección en el *JSON*. Al ver la pestaña de problemas de la terminal, me dice que no hay problemas. A pesar de haber hecho todo eso, el cursor en la consola se mantiene fijo, la pantalla esta vacía (al contrario de cuando ejecuto el *GitBash* en el escritorio o cualquier otra carpeta) y no puedo escribir ningún comando. ¿Alguna ayuda que me puedan proveer?

[image: Direccion especificada en el JSON + pestaña de problemas de la terminal]

[image: Queriendo elegir la terminal predeterminada donde no aparece GitBash + ventana de comando de la terminal en blanco y sin poder escribir]

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregar la siguiente linea en tu archivo settings.json

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
```